# Show errors on iis7 using wcf rest service?

Tags: .net, wcf, iis-7

I got a wcf rest service and when I put it on iss7 and run the give me this

```
The server encountered an error processing the request.
See server logs for more details.
```

but the logs does not say anything. so my question is how can I put those errors up?

Comment: Have you enabled tracing (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) in your service?

Comment: yes and still does not work.

Comment: Does the path which your trace file is being directed to grants write access to the account which IIS is running (usually NETWORK SERVICE)? IIRC by default that account can't write to hardly any folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according my needs ( debuging ) just put this to true on my service behavior  and got the exceptions.

```
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods that you can use to get detailed errors. Basically, they all work the same as the one described by `BlaShadow`. Here is a [blog post](http://nsamteladze.blogspot.com/2013/07/enable-verbosely-errors-in-wcf-data.html) about that.

I'm aware of 3 way to get nicer errors:

1. Set `UseVerboseErrors' in`InitializeService' method. However, this won't give you anything if your error occurs before `InitializeService' is called (which happens).
2. Set `IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults` to true using an attribute before your service class.
3. Set `IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults` to true using web.config.